# Error about Single Signon using Azure AD

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, azure, azure-active-directory

I tried to implement a single sign-on app following the tutorial here

http://geoffwebbercross.blogspot.com/2014/05/adding-azure-ad-single-sign-on-to.html

I added an active directory in azure and added a user for this tenant. Then I built a small app in VS2013. I used organizational accounts and typed in the domain name, logged in and created the project. While creating the project, there poped up a dialogue box said

Request_BadRequest: Invalid value found for property 'identifierUris' fo resource 'Application'

And I closed that. I tried to run the project on my local machine. It will have the information like this.

```
HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error

The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.



Detailed Error Information:



Module
   IIS Web Core 

Notification
   Unknown 

Handler
   Not yet determined 

Error Code
   0x80070032 

Config Error
   The configuration section 'system.identityModel' cannot be read because it is missing a section declaration.  

Config File




Requested URL
   http:

Physical Path


Logon Method
   Not yet determined 

Logon User
   Not yet determined 

Request Tracing Directory
   D:\My Documents\IISExpress\TraceLogFiles\ 




Config Source:
   34:   </system.web>
   35:   <system.identityModel>
   36:     <identityConfiguration>




More Information:
This error occurs when there is a problem reading the configuration file for the Web server or Web application. In some cases, the event logs may contain more information about what caused this error.

If you see the text "There is a duplicate 'system.web.extensions/scripting/scriptResourceHandler' section defined", this error is because you are running a .NET Framework 3.5-based application in .NET Framework 4. If you are running WebMatrix, to resolve this problem, go to the Settings node to set the .NET Framework version to ".NET 2". You can also remove the extra sections from the web.config file. 
View more information »
```

Any ideas of how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the root cause was (why you got the error while creating the project), but the following should resolve the error you're seeing when running the app.

In the the `<configSections>` section of your `web.config` you need to have the `system.identityModel` section defined.  The entries should look something like this:

```
<configSections>
  <section name="system.identityModel" type="System.IdentityModel.Configuration.SystemIdentityModelSection, System.IdentityModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
  <section name="system.identityModel.services" type="System.IdentityModel.Services.Configuration.SystemIdentityModelServicesSection, System.IdentityModel.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
</configSections>
```